Is there a ros2 controller for four wheels differential drive mobile platform?
Is there an existing ros2 controller for four wheels differential drive mobile platform? In the current ros2-control controllers, I couldn't find a four wheel differential drive controller. Can somebody point the direction?

The diff_drive controller supports several wheels per side (the wheel_names parameters are arrays). One limitation: They have to have the same wheel_separation.
